# Is_callable and self

Tags: php, class, callable

Oddly enough, the following both expressions dump bool(true):

```
class B {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump(is_callable(array($this, "z")), is_callable(array("self", "z")));
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public function z() {}
}

new C();
```

I had only expected the first to be true.
If I call `self::z()` from inside `B`, an error is shown.

Is there another, simple way to find out if class B contains a callable method `z` (other than using the ReflectionMethod class - that more like a last resort)?

Update: I found that `is_callable(array(__CLASS__, "z"))` displays the correct result.. again, oddly enough.

Comment: Just use __CLASS__, what is the problem. Why do you have to use self?

Comment: @true `self` should reference the own class. `is_callable` interprets `self` as `$this`. My conclusion is there is a problem with `is_callable`.

Comment: `__CLASS__` won't work because it will refer to class B, not C

Comment: @true well that's exactly what is desired

Comment: Even if `self` did work, it would still refer to class B, not C

Comment: _“I had only expected the first to be true. If I call self::z() from inside B, an error is shown”_ – yes, but you don’t actually _have_ an instance of `B` here, because the `__construct` method implicitly gets called “from” the instance of `C` that you are creating. `C` does not have its own constructor, so the one of its parent class `B` is invoked – and at this point, `$this` is the instance of `C` that has a `z` method, and not of `B` that doesn’t. That you can’t _call_ `z` from within somewhere else in a `B` instance doesn’t contradict that.

Comment: And if you were just to call `new B()` after your test with `C` in the above code, you get `bool(false)` _two_ times – which is also to be expected.

Comment: @CBroe I know the difference between `$this` and `self`. Which is why only `is_callable(array($this, "z"))` should have returned true in this case. As `$this` is the instance of `C` - which makes `z` callable for `$this`. `self` however refers to `B`, and calling `z` via `self` from inside `B` unsurprisingly results in an error: that's why `is_callable(array("self", "z"))` should have returned false.

Answer (score -1):

This code executes fine and correctly as it should be:-

```
<?php 

class B {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump(is_callable(array($this, "z")), 
        is_callable(array("self", "z")));
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public function z() {}
}

new C();
?>
```

Output: bool(true) bool(true).
Let me try to explain why; `is_callable(array($this, "z")` 
$this`refers to the current class`using constructor and namely class B; And
the output is correct.
For the second callable Method, calls a function in a child class and you are 
using **self** for the callable as a parameter.

As the child class inherits all properties and characteristics of the Parent class, it 
inherits **self** scope call too, and  reaches the scope to be callable in 
the child class. While talking talking to parent class using **self** in callback function
you are talking to its child classes too. The callback function considers the child 
class as the parent class, because all properties and characteristics are available in
the child class.

```
is_callable(array("self", "z")))  Her you are checking if z is callable
```

and it is callable under class C, because it is child class of B.

This is your code with little modification.

```
<?php 

    class B {
        public function __construct() {
            var_dump(is_callable(array($this, "z")), 
            is_callable(array("self", "z")),
            is_callable(array("self", "d")));
        }
    }
    class C extends B {
        public function z() {}
    }

    new C();
    ?>
```

Output:- bool(true) bool(true) bool(false)
Last one evaluates to false, because it does not exist and therefore it cannot be called as function.

Comment: The constructor has been placed inside `B`, not `C`. `self` refers to `B` (which is why `self::z()` causes an error). `is_callable` is not only theoretically wrong here, it is also *practically wrong*, since what it says about callability proves to be incorrect!

Comment: This inherits the callback function from the parent class ; Inheriting from the parent scope

Comment: I'm not talking about `$this`, but about `self`.